# MAC OSX dylib's and how to use them

Tags: macos, dylib

I downloaded and installed (I think) gtk on the Mac OSX (Lion). Compilation of test program went fine after getting all the -I's correct.  Now the link is failing. A grep for the missing entrypoints

```
_gtk_init
_gtk_window_new
... 11 more
```

found them in 
    /Users/ccpalmer/gtk/inst/lib/libgtk-quartz-2.0.0.dylib
    /Users/ccpalmer/gtk/inst/lib/libgtk-quartz-2.0.dylib

Being less familiar with OSX's underlying Unix, I'm not sure how to get thru the link step.  I must admit, I've never encountered a "dylib" before.

Are there any OSX dev smarties out there who might shed some light on my mystery?

Charles

Comment: A `dylib` is a Mach-O shared object file, similar to a `so` on ELF systems and a `dll` on PE (EXE) systems.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the command line you tried that didn't work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As moshbear commented above, `dylib` files are how shared libraries are packaged on Mac OS X.  To use such a shared library, you need to pass two switches to your compiler, `-L` and `-l`.  The first adds the directory containing your `dylib` to the linker's library search path, and the second specifies the library to link against.  Something like this, for a fictional `libfoo.dylib` that lives in `/usr/mylibs`:

```
clang code.c -L/usr/mylibs -lfoo
```

Comment: Codesigning on Copy will be important. Have a look at it.